# Adding Service Reference Error : mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx?WSDL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have been trying to add https:///mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx?WSDL to my service References after upgrading from CRM4 to 2011:

the error message:

```
There was an error downloading 'https://ServerName/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx?WSDL'.
 The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://<ServerName>/mscrmservices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
```

Have also tried "https:///mscrmservices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx" as seen in error message but get same return.

When accessing via web it works fine just adding as a reference in Visual Studio

other urls work ok such as https:///XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0

this link suggests it should be fine:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334316.aspx

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this was a weird one but i managed to get Visual Studio to download the service using the IP of the server as @ccellar had highlighted there was something wrong with the "server/{org}" part of the url i was using the "Host name" but anyway using the IP has worked!

```
https://{IP}/mscrmservices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx
```

If you dont know your IP use http://network-tools.com/ lookup

Hope this helps anyone who has a problem with this

Thanks @CCellar for your guidance

Comment: It then looks like you haven't either configured IFD or there is some problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the organization name in your url. The url should look like this `http{s}://server/{org}/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx?wsdl`

Comment: {https}://crm.{Name}.co.uk/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx?WSDL is what we are using {Name} being replaced with the name: this url works on web

Comment: @RichardDewhirst 'crm' is the name of the crm organization?